# Are VLANs necessary to segment WiFi SSID to secure traffic?

Tags: wifi, vlans

WiFi routers offer the ability to configure multiple SSIDs. Equally some routers also enable the option to configure virtual networks (VLANs).

If the requirement is to secure WiFi traffic such that as users on one SSID cannot communicate with another, is it necessary to assign SSIDs to VLANs?

Based on an [analysis of the "Hole 196" WPA2 attack](https://community.arubanetworks.com/t5/Community-Tribal-Knowledge-Base/Analysis-of-quot-Hole-196-quot-WPA2-Attack/ta-p/25382), it seems that WiFi isolation provides a layer of security in that no communication can occur between clients on the same wireless network.

- If yes, is there still a requirement to segment WiFi traffic via VLANs? What benefit does this deliver?
- If clients are unable to communicate with one another, does it mean that a compromised device cannot affect other devices on the network?